# How do I get usage data about the what views and datasets are being used/queried in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I need usage data on the dataset and views in BigQuery. I want a count of how many queries were ran against all the different datasets and views. My goal is to understand what datasets and views are currently being used.

I looked in the Audit Log, however I'm not able to export all the records into excel for analysis. I am only able to export max 300 logs for a specific day. Is there a way to run a query in BigQuery that will give me this data instead of exporting from the Audit Log?

Answer (score 2):

Yes—you can set up an [export "sink" in Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs/#stackdriver-logging-exports) to get the data into BigQuery for analysis. They also provide documentation of how the [payload fields are transformed](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/bigquery) on export.

The first link includes some notes on filtering to just the `BigQueryAuditMetadata` type, but note that you can also filter on fields inside of the payload by using an [advanced log filter](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-filters) (e.g. if you only want to see which tables are being written, read, only include certain users, etc.).

Obviously you can just stream everything into BigQuery if you want, but filtering can help keep the noise down.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, really appreciate your help! I created an export sink per the documentation and filtering for resource.type="bigquery_dataset". I see the dataset created in BigQuery. How do I query against this data? The dataset does not have any tables or views.

Comment: Actually, after refreshing BigQuery I see that there are tables in the dataset now. However, looks like it's taking some time to load and I'm seeing some streaming buffer statistics. Do you know how long it'll take to load three month's worth of audit logs?

Comment: @Ck87 It really depends on the amount of activity on your account (including indirect access like Data Studio connections that can add lots of noise). In addition to recent data being synced, there can be a 90-minute delay until the data gets partitioned—but the streaming buffer can still be queried against (it will just will have a `_PARTITIONTIME` of `NULL`). If you haven't dealt with streaming inserts, you may want to take a look at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery . If this ends up working out, feel free to accept the answer; if not, I'm happy to help further.