# If a user queries a public BigQuery database can the data owner see the query that was executed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Consider two different projects: `their-project` (to which I have no access) and `my-project` to which I have high-level access. If a user in `their-project` queries data stored in a BigQuery table that is associated with `my-project`, can I see the query? Or, failing that, can I see how many queries users executed?

*Background* My current project is considering releasing some data in BigQuery. But we would like to see how users are accessing this data so we can decide where to spend our effort in enhancing the released data. I looked at [this question about usage data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56938856/309334) but is not clear whether the solution proposed would work when the query is part of someone else's project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot see their query if you don't have access to the logs in `their-project`.

However, with Audit Logs in `my-project` you *will* see the identity of users that access your tables.  But it stops there.  You will know which columns & tables people are reading, but not the actual content of their query.

As for the *count* of queries, there is some correlation between count of audit logs and count of queries, but my hunch is that counting audit logs will only put you in the ballpark.